# Can I wire a GFCI so that each receptacle is controlled by it's own switch?

Tags: gfci

Can I wire a GFCI so that each receptacle is controlled by it's own switch? This is for a water fountain pump and light. Diagrams, please.

Comment: Note that it may be simpler to just install two gfci's, each on its own switches circuit.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean a GFCI duplex receptacle, no.

The way to do this would be to use a GFCI (either duplex receptacle type or barefaced) for the GFCI function, and from its "LOAD" terminals provide power to two switches, which you would connect to the outlet you wanted to control - if part of a duplex outlet, you would break the tabs connecting the two sides of the outlet (at least on the hot side) to have independent switch function.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to accomplish this,  is to install the GFCI device *before* the switch. The easiest solution, would be to install a GFCI breaker to protect the entire circuit.

The receptacles on a GFCI receptacle are connected to the GFCI circuitry internally, and cannot be separated without modifying the device (which is not recommended).

[image: Split receptacle GFCI protection]